# How to get signature of type in FSharp interactive?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

When I define a type in fsi, I get a signature like the following:

```
> type UserInfo = { firstName: string ; lastName: string } ;;
type UserInfo =
  {firstName: string;
   lastName: string;}
```

Is there a way to get this signature within fsi at some later point ? ie. given a type `UserInfo` available in current context, get the representation:

```
type UserInfo =
  {firstName: string;
   lastName: string;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `typeof` or `typedefof`:

```ml
> typeof<UserInfo>;;
```

Although it won't give you exactly what you want, the field names and types can be found under `DeclaredFields` or `DeclaredProperties`.

```
val it: System.Type =
  FSI_0002+UserInfo
    {Assembly = FSI-ASSEMBLY2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null;
     ...
     DeclaredFields = [|System.String firstName@; System.String lastName@|];
     ...
     UnderlyingSystemType = ...;}
```